# Android Pause and Resume when video recording with FFMpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-capture, video-recording

I wanna make an Android application. When user touch the button, will start recording a video, and leave the button pause it. Again start to touch I will resume to recording. I searched on the Internet, I can make it with FFMpeg library. But I can't find any example or document. I have generated ffmpeg .so libraries for Android.

Can you give any example links or tutorial or something else.

Thanks

Comment: I know nothing of Android, but perhaps you can simply suspend and resume the `ffmpeg` process with the button. See [Is there a way to pause and resume FFmpeg encoding?](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/17069/1760) for some examples.

Comment: Usually, `ffmpeg` is not the best tool to record video on Android. The easiest way to start is with MediaRecorder. Check the official [example code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaRecorder).